# Should we close questions that aren't well asked, even if it's obvious what the OP wants?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185117/software-center-not-opening) is an example.

My first reaction was to vote for closure as **Not a real question**, yet the title says what's wrong, and the OP gave his error message.

Therefore, it doesn't really fall in the scope of **NARQ** as defined in the "Close" popup:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Should we tolerate these questions? Or should we close them, even though we *can* tell what's being asked, simply to discourage badly formatted questions?

Comment: Edit edit edit edit edit!

Comment: If we know what they are asking, then we should edit it to make it more clear, of course without changing the original purpose of the question. The only way a person is going to learn what a quality question looks like, is that if we teach them, and closing the question won't help teach them anything other then that we are intolerant of new users that don't know how things work yet.

Comment: @TheX You might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we know what they are asking, then we should edit it to make it more clear, of course without changing the original purpose of the question. The only way a person is going to learn what a quality question looks like, is that if we teach them, and closing the question won't help teach them anything other then that we are intolerant of new users that don't know how things work yet. Remember we all start new, and require learning... some of us learn faster then others, but that is just life.

Comment: Exceedingly well said.